# Log4J send tons of emails for one exception?

Tags: java, email, logging, log4j

I configured Log4J to send me emails when an exception occurs, but when it does, instead of sending me one email, I get A LOT of emails (like 10) for the same exception.

I don't know what's wrong.

Here's my configuration :

```
<configuration>
    <conversionRule conversionWord="coloredLevel" converterClass="play.api.Logger$ColoredLevel" />

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
     <file>${application.home}/logs/application.log</file>
     <encoder>
       <pattern>%date - [%level] - from %logger in %thread %n%message%n%xException%n</pattern>
     </encoder>
   </appender>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%coloredLevel %logger{15} - %message%n%xException{5}</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="EMAIL" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender">
        <smtpHost>smtp.mandrillapp.com</smtpHost>
        <smtpPort>587</smtpPort>
        <SSL>true</SSL>
        <username>my@email.com</username>
        <password>******</password>
        <to>me@account.com</to>
        <from>support@app.com</from>
        <subject>[App error] - %ex{short}</subject>

        <cyclicBufferTracker class="ch.qos.logback.core.spi.CyclicBufferTracker">
          <bufferSize>5</bufferSize>
        </cyclicBufferTracker>

        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.html.HTMLLayout">
            <pattern>%ex{full}</pattern>
        </layout>

        <!--<layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <pattern>%d%n%throwable{short}%n%n%xEx{full}</pattern>
        </layout>-->
    </appender>

    <logger name="play" level="INFO" />
    <logger name="application" level="INFO"/>

    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="EMAIL" />
    </root>
    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root> 
</configuration>
```

Comment: Cyril have you found the answer? I'm facing same issue.

Comment: No, I'm sorry. I can recommend you to try things like https://papertrailapp.com/ for example, but that's all :/